# Julia: Creating a method for a subtype (LinearModel)

Tags: types, julia, glm

I am trying to create a method for the LinearModel subtype of the GLM package. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work:

```
using DataFrames, GLM, RDatasets

iris = dataset("datasets", "iris")

fit = lm(@formula(SepalLength ~ PetalWidth), iris)

function print_r2(fit::GLM.LinearModel)

    R2 = r2(fit)
    println("The model's R2 is $R2.")

end

print_r2(fit)
```

And errors:

```
MethodError: no method matching print_r2(::StatsModels.DataFrameRegressionModel{GLM.LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Array{Float64,1}},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,Base.LinAlg.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}},Array{Float64,2}})
Closest candidates are:
  print_r2(::GLM.LinearModel) at In[1]:9
```

Do I have to specify the whole type?

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the type a bit differently:

```
import StatsBase

function print_r2(fit::StatsBase.RegressionModel)
    R2 = r2(fit)
    println("The model's R2 is $R2.")
end
```

or `fit::StatsModels.DataFrameRegressionModel` if you want to be more specific.

The problem is that your `fit` is not of `GLM.LinearModel` type:

```
julia> fit isa GLM.LinearModel
false
```

You can check its type like this:

```
julia> typeof(fit)
StatsModels.DataFrameRegressionModel{GLM.LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Array{Float64,1}},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,Base.LinAlg.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}},Array{Float64,2}}
```

As a side note: `fit` is not a very fortunate name as it conflicts with the function name exported by `StatsBase`.

Comment: Thanks for these answers and suggestions (you're right about that fit name thing)!! but how to specify the LinearModel subtype, so the function is not general to all GLMs but only to LMs?

Comment: If this is what you want then I think this will work `StatsModels.DataFrameRegressionModel{<:GLM.LinearModel}` in the method signature. EDIT: then if even if you create a linear model using `glm` function it will be treated as GLM not LM and not be accepted by your function.